# How can I get this code to run in my worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

all
I am trying to run a code that will check if one cell in a row is "service" then if so I want it to check the cells in the rows below in a different column if they say "clinic" the if that is true subtract the value in a separate cell in the clinic row from the original service row if the dates of the clinic are within the service. I believe I have gotten at least somewhat close but I cannot get it to apply to any cells in the worksheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Column 11 is the column that is either service or clinic).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Service_Start_Date As Range
Dim Service_End_Date As Range
Dim Clinic_Date As Range
Dim Activity_Type As Range
Dim Total_Days As Range

Set Activity_Type = Columns(11)
Set Service_Start_Date = Columns("J")
Set Service_End_Date = Columns("K")
Set Total_Days = Columns("M")
col = "J"
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10000:
    If Cells(i, 11) = "Service" Then:
        For J = 1 To 100:
            While Cells(i + 1, 11) = "Clinic"
                If Cells(i + 1, Service_Start_Date) <= Cells(i, Service_End_Date) And Cells(i + 1, Service_Start_Date) >= Cells(i, Service_Start_Date) Then:
                    Range(i, Total_Days).Value1 -Range(i + J, Total_Days).Value2
            Wend
        Next J

Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: What would you like `Service_Start_Date` to be? It looks to be a range. All column "J:J". What do you want, in fact to compare when you use `If Cells(i + 1, Service_Start_Date) <= Cells(i, Service_End_Date)`?

Comment: You said "in a different column if they say Clinic" but you are checking column 11 K, the same as "Service" ?

Comment: Setting "Service_Start_Date" or "Service_End_Date" as a `range variable` will not work when using Cells(row, column), you need to use `"J"`or the number `10` to identify the column, or a `number variable` or a `string variable for "K"`.   Also, if `Service_End_Date` was a number variable, then `Cells(i, Service_End_Date)` would be the same as `Cells(i, 11) = "Service"`, I don't think you have service and date in the same cell. A sample of you data would help to solve your problems.